# How to create read-only column/cell using microsoft excel graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to create a column with non editable. I didn't find any APIs in Microsoft graph.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
include [example] of your code, include the current result, include the expected result.
See [ask]

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such Microsoft Graph API having this feature. You can raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may implement it in future.